# Can I dual boot a Nexus 4 with Touch preview?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Can I  dual boot a Nexus 4 with Touch preview?

I have installed Ubuntu touch preview on my phone, but I cannot use it as primary device. I still like to have it for development and testing.

Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: There is a dual boot solution for Nexus 7: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2011403. Maybe it could be adapted to Nexus 4 as well.

Answer (score -1):

Well, a real dual boot like with a pc is not possible, but maybe [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drx2.bootmanager) works.

It runs under rooted Android and you can select what ROM to boot next reboot. Maybe worth a try

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -2):

It certainly seems possible and should be.

Listed here on how to do it: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2165491

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Provide possibly an abridged version of the content here to help create a higher quality answer

Comment: nexus 4 is not galaxy nexus

Answer (score -2):

Download boot manager, create new partition, flash cyanogenmod in second partition, and install Ubuntu over it like you normally would.